# What is the right expectation for a return type of Query<T> for unit testing?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing

For a stream matcher, we can use `emits(expectedData)` to expect what a stream returns. And for Future, we can use `completion(expectedData)`, But how about a return type of `Query<T>`? Please check my example below.

```
group('collectionQuery test', () {
      final service = FirestoreService(firestore: fakeService);
      
      test('expect to return the collection', () async {
        for (var i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
          final path = 'collections/id10$i';
          await service.setData(path: path, data: testData[i].toMap());
        }

        final Query<Post> result = service.collectionQuery(
            path: collectionPath,
            fromMap: ((snapshot, options) =>
                Post.fromMap(snapshot.data()!, snapshot.id)),
            toMap: ((post, options) => post.toMap()));

        expect(result, //whatIsTheExpectationHere(testData));
      });
    });
```

Here is the actual function under test:

```
Query<T> collectionQuery<T>({
    required String path,
    required T Function(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
            SnapshotOptions? options)
        fromMap,
    required Map<String, Object?> Function(T, SetOptions? options) toMap,
  }) {
    Query<T> query = firestore
        .collection(path)
        .withConverter<T>(fromFirestore: fromMap, toFirestore: toMap);
    return query;
}
```

Comment: _Should you_ **actually** care about the concrete type of `result` - or just the values of its elements? (I'm not a Flutter nor Firebase user, but I assume that `Query<T>` type is an abstract interface type, not a concrete class type, right?)

Comment: im testing whether the result is the expected data..I used `expect(result, emits(testData));`  but it says `emits` cant be used because the actual data is not a stream.

Comment: @Dai i included the function under test.

Answer (score 0):

since type `Query<T>` doesnt have a matcher, another option that can be done is to convert it to Future/Stream in order to use the `completion` or `emits` matchers. In my case i converted into future and my test passed.

```html
test('expect to return the collection', () async {
        for (var i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
          final path = 'collections/id10$i';
          await service.setData(path: path, data: testData[i].toMap());
        }

        final Query<Post> result = service.collectionQuery(
            path: collectionPath,
            fromMap: ((snapshot, options) =>
                Post.fromMap(snapshot.data()!, snapshot.id)),
            toMap: ((post, options) => post.toMap()));

          expect(result, isA<Query<Post>>());

        final actualData = result.get().then((snapshot) {
          final result = snapshot.docs
              .map((snapshot) => snapshot.data())
              .where((value) => value != null)
              .toList();

          return result;
        });

        expect(actualData, completion(testData));
      });
```